# FP or typelevel tools to groupBy on deep leaf in nested data?

Tags: scala, group-by, nested, scalaz, shapeless

I got a deeply nested datastructure:

```
Seq[Seq[(String, Seq[(String, Seq[(String, Try[Boolean])])], Long)]]
```

Is there a *nice functional way* to groupBy on Try.isFailure?

With Shapeless it is possible to search in arbitrary nested datastructures, as can be seen [here](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/shapeless/examples/deepsearch.scala). But finding is only one part of my problem. I saw zippers and lenses, they are nice but afaik they are not the right tool here.

For info, the data represents results of some test code. The layers are: 
permutations of configurations => tested component  => mutation on data  => testing code. Strings are descriptions, long is the time it took to finish for each component test.
I want to create two lists, one with all failures keeping all the info where and when  they happened keeping exceptions as info, and one corresponding one for successes.

Is there a solution out there already?

Note: the most sensible approach for that particular case would be to redesign my testcode such that two lists, one failurelist and one successlist are created from the start. But still, I'd like to know. This kind of problem doesn't seem to be uncommon.

Comment: Do you expect to have this same problem with structures of different depths, and also want to abstract over those structures? If the answer to both of those questions is "yes" then shapeless might be what you're looking for. If not then an answer like @cmbaxter's is what you're after.

Comment: @MilesSabin In that particular case, no. But still I'd be interested to know which particular piece of shapeless might help solve this kind of sorting problem (besides the mere finding). Keep up the good work... Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may not be the most creative solution, but you could `partition` the outermost Seq as follows:

```
val partitioned = seq.partition{ s =>
  val flat = s.map(_._2).flatten.map(_._2).flatten
  flat.find(tup => tup._2.isFailure).isDefined
}
```

In this example, the first line in the `partition` body flattens out the nested structure so you are left with the inner most `Seq`.  Then, from there, the predicate condition to return for the `partition` call is derived from seeing if the inner most `Seq` contains at least one `Failure`.  What you are left with is a tuple where the first `Seq` is the outermost items that have `failures in their nested structures and the second one is ones where no failures occurred.

This is probably not the best performing solution, but it's succinct as far as code lines is concerned.  In fact, you could even do it in one line as follows:

```
val partitioned = seq.partition(_.map(_._2).flatten.map(_._2).flatten.find(_._2.isFailure).isDefined)
```

Comment: You can clean things up even further by changing the map/flatten combo to just `flatMap` as follows:  
  
    `val partitioned = seq.partition{ s =>
      val flat = s.flatMap(_._2).flatMap(_._2)
      flat.find(tup => tup._2.isFailure).isDefined
    }`

Comment: @cmbaxter I forgot to thank you for your answer. I was hoping for some FP magic, but apparently there isn't.